# Why javascript promise doesn't async in for loop?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I have code like this:

```
const loop1 = length => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    let b = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) b = b + i
    resolve(b)
  } catch (e) {
    reject(e)
  }
})

const loop2 = length => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    let b = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) b = b + i
    resolve(b)
  } catch (e) {
    reject(e)
  }
})

const startTime = new Date().getTime()

loop1(10000000000).then(result => {
  const endTime = new Date().getTime()
  const duration = endTime - startTime
  console.log(`loop1: ${duration}`, result)
}).catch(error => console.log('loop1 error:', error))

loop2(1).then(result => {
  const endTime = new Date().getTime()
  const duration = endTime - startTime
  console.log(`loop2: ${duration}`, result)
}).catch(error => console.log('loop2 error:', error))

const endTime = new Date().getTime()
const duration = endTime - startTime
console.log('duration', duration)
```

Why are the results like this?:

```
root@ububtu:~$ node .
duration 15539
loop1: 15545 49999999990067860000
loop2: 15545 0
```

Why isn't the result like this?:

```
root@ububtu:~$ node .
duration 0
loop2: 5 0
loop1: 15545 49999999990067860000
```

Why should wait loop1 for give the result?
Why not passed loop1 to give result loop2 first?
And why the duration time is not < 1 seconds but more than 15 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you pass into the `Promise` constructor (the *promise executor* function) is called **synchronously**. That's so that it can start the asynchronous process (whatever it is) that the promise represents.

So in your code, `loop1`'s executor function runs synchronously, then the promise is returned, then `loop2`'s executor function is run synchronously; later, the fulfillment handlers are called asynchronously.

Remember: Promises don't turn a synchronous thing into an asynchronous thing. They just provide a standardized means of *observing* the results of things that are *already* asynchronous.

If you update your code to model asynchronous operations (in this case I'll use `setTimeout`), you'll see `loop2`'s handler called before `loop1`'s, since it fulfills earlier:

```js
const loop1 = length => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, length, length)
})

const loop2 = length => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, length, length)
})

const startTime = new Date().getTime()

loop1(800).then(result => {
  const endTime = new Date().getTime()
  const duration = endTime - startTime
  console.log(`loop1: ${duration}`, result)
}).catch(error => console.log('loop1 error:', error))

loop2(1).then(result => {
  const endTime = new Date().getTime()
  const duration = endTime - startTime
  console.log(`loop2: ${duration}`, result)
}).catch(error => console.log('loop2 error:', error))

const endTime = new Date().getTime()
const duration = endTime - startTime
console.log('duration', duration)
```